# SQL Connection String failing to connect SQL Instance

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I am attempting to debug an application, but when I run it I get the following error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I've opened up the 1433 port and double-checked it's open and reachable from my current location. I've also enabled TCP/IP remote connections and can connect remotely using SQL Server Studio Manager.

The connection string I'm using is:

```
Data Source=xx.xx.xxx.xx, 1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=KnightOwl-Demo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=KnightOwlGentleshaw; Password=xxxxxx
```

I'm 90%sure there's something wrong with the connection string but I'm not sure what?

Comment: are you able to connect in SSMS ?

Comment: Yes, I can connect from SSMS

Comment: and from same machine ? with same username, server url ?

Comment: Yep all the same details from the same machine and location

Comment: Can you also add an exception for the SQL Server Browser. (udp port 1434) and make sure service is running on server

Comment: Can you connect with the ODBC manager in the Control Panel?

Comment: Also do you have SQL Server Authentication enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not sure about the Connection string, use a udl file for testing:

1. Create a new text file.
2. Change the extension to **.udl** (e.g. `1.txt` to `1.udl`)
3. Go to the `Connection` tab
4. Insert your credentials (*Servername\instance* , user name + password / Windows security etc)
5. Check the `Allow saving password` check box
6. Click on `Test Connection` and get a success message.
7. Click on OK (this will close the form)
8. Open the `1.udl` file in a text editor - It will contain the connection string that was used for the successful connection

Now you can compare the connection strings / use the one you now that works...

Good luck!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Data Source=xx.xx.xxx.xx;Initial Catalog=KnightOwl-Demo;Persist Security Info=True;
```