# Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to connect my ASP.NET Core MVC application to SQL Server. I'm using the Visual Studio for mac.

I wrote the connection string like below :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
   "DevDBConn": "Server={serverName}\\{instanceName};Database={DBName};User ID={userID};Password={password};Trusted_Connection=True;"
},
```

I'm pretty sure that my DB Server's info is correct, but I get this error:

> System.Exception: Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started.
>   System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Does anyone have an idea why there is an error?

Comment: "SQL Server Browser" is a separate service on the server running SQL Server. Its job in life is to direct connecting clients to Named Instances of SQL Server (since you can have multiple instances of SQL Server running on the same server). The error message is telling you that the "SQL Server Browser" service is not running on the target server.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436589/sql-connection-string-failing-to-connect-sql-instance

Comment: Add IP address for the server instead of name

Comment: If you're using a trusted connection, why are you passing a User ID and Password? It's one or the other

Answer (score 1):

You might face this issue when using Docker with Visual Studio IDE. To address the problem, consider the following steps:

**Update Connection String:**

Modify your connection string to include the correct port. Here's an example:

```json
"DevDBConn": "Server={serverName}\\{instanceName}, {port};Database={DBName};User ID={userID};Password={password};Trusted_Connection=True;"


You might also want to enable tcp on  sql server configuration manager > network configurations
```

Answer (score 0):

Open run command (WIN+R), press **services.msc** and press ENTER. The services are visible now. Check SQLServer (instance name) and SQL Server Browser are running.

Comment: I checked both of them are running. But still same error occured